# Firebase auth breaks with cross origin isolation (i.e. when using Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy)

Tags: firebase-authentication, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

I am trying to make a website cross origin isolated, and enabled the following headers on my site:

https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

Firebase auth uses a  call to:

https://<AUTH_DOMAIN>/__/auth/iframe?apiKey=<API_KEY>&appName=[DEFAULT]

This gets blocked if you and makes authentication fail.

> Because your site has the Cross-Origin Embedder Policy (COEP) enabled, each resource must specify a suitable Cross-Origin Resource Policy (CORP). This behavior prevents a document from loading cross-origin resources which don’t explicitly grant permission to be loaded.
> To solve this, add the following to the resource’s response header:
> Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-site if the resource and your site are served from the same site.
> Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin if the resource is served from another location than your website. ⚠️If you set this header, any website can embed this resource.

How does one fix this? It seems like the root issue is that firebase needs to set a header on their side ?

Comment: Is this issue fixed ? I am also experiencing the same issue.

Comment: The workaround I ended up using was make auth work on an non COEP enabled page, then redirect the user to the COEP page. But I am not sure if this got fixed or not.

Really wish someone from Firebase responded to this, this is kind of a bad bug.

Comment: Any news on this? Also experiencing this issue when trying to use OPFS which requires those same headers to be set.

Comment: I swear this worked like 2 weeks ago as the only thing preventing crossOriginIsolation on my site was the Discord widget (which they fixed) but now Google Login/Firebase is not working.. :'(